# `\center` and size of `\frac` in my code

Tags: math-mode, fractions

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{secdot}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\title{\vspace{-3em} Quantum Mechanics}
\author{David Ge}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Operators In Schroedinger Equation}
\onehalfspacing
In quantum mechanics, a question that concerns us all is whether light is particles or waves. Let's first assume light is wave, so it must satisfy the wave equation:

\vspace{-1em}
\begin{align}
    \left (\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial z^2} \right)-
        \frac{1}{c^2}  \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} & = 0 \\
    \nabla^2 \psi - \frac{1}{c^2}  \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} & = 0
\end{align}

Naturally, we construct the solution of this wave equation:

\begin{center}
    $ \psi(x,y,z;t) = \psi_{0} \, e^{i \, [\, k (x+y+z)- \omega t + \phi_{0}\, ]}$
\end{center}

Here, we can set the initial condition $\phi_{0} = 0$, and we would like to explore the 1D case:
\begin{center}
    $ \psi(x,t) = \psi_{x,0} \, e^{i \, (kx- \omega t)}    $
\end{center}

Now, we lay down all the foundation, and we want to express the momentum and energy operators, by using the solution of the wave function. By observing the equation:

\begin{center}
$ E = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V  $
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The above is my code, and I have two questions to ask:

1. I feel really annoying to type `\begin{center} \end{center}` each time when I need to type down the equation. I'm wondering is there an easier way to accomplish this?
2. See `$ E = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V  $`. Here, the size of the fraction looks ugly, can anyone help me because I don't know how to ask this question.

Comment: for centering a one-line equation, use `\[ ... \]`.  (haven't got time to test anything.)

Comment: Don't leave blank lines before displays. You won't need that `\vspace{-1em}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
Naturally, we construct the solution of this wave equation:

\begin{center}
    $ \psi(x,y,z;t) = \psi_{0} \, e^{i \, [\, k (x+y+z)- \omega t + \phi_{0}\, ]}$
\end{center}
```

use

```
Naturally, we construct the solution of this wave equation: 
\[ \psi(x,y,z;t) = \psi_{0} \, e^{i \, [\, k (x+y+z)- \omega t + \phi_{0}\, ]}\]
```

To type fractions inline and have the same output as displayed one use `\dfrac{}{}`. **But** if you are inserting fractions inside `\[ \]` it is not necessary. Just use `\frac{}{}`.

Comment: +1 But just a comment, almost every `\dfrac` I've ever seen is “wrongly used”, at least in my opinion. Better to use `\frac` and let the style decide.

Comment: @Manuel, yes, I agree. But some people wants to have displayed fractions inline.

Comment: @Manuel Am I doing it right? `\[ E = \dfrac{p^2}{2m} + V  \]`

Comment: @Lawerance, see my edited answer. It is not necessary.